# Trying to make my 2D character double jump - it's not working and I don't know why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm making a 2D platformer. Here's my code so far. The character jumps only when touching the ground as it should - but the code for double jumping doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. I'm new at scripting and I don't understand what I did wrong?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 12f, jumpHeight = 30f;
    Rigidbody2D playerBody;
    Transform playerTrans, tagGround;
    bool isGrounded = false;
    public LayerMask playerMask;
    public float maxJumps = 2;
    public float jumpsLeft = 2;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        playerBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerTrans = this.transform;
        tagGround = GameObject.Find(this.name + "/tag_Ground").transform;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast(playerTrans.position, tagGround.position, playerMask);
        Move();
        Jump();
        DoubleJump();

    }

    private void Move()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(move, playerBody.velocity.y);
    }

    private void Jump()

    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {


            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(playerBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight);


            }


        }

    }
    private void DoubleJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && jumpsLeft > 0)
        {
            Jump();
            jumpsLeft--;
        }

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            jumpsLeft = maxJumps;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try asking at [gamedev.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make much sense. You should handle your jumping in one method and handle it something like this:

```
private void HandleJump()
{
    if(isGrounded) {
        jumpsLeft = maxJumps;
    }

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && jumpsLeft > 0) {
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(playerBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
        jumpsLeft--;
    }
}
```

This way you can make triple jumps or however many jumps you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your Jump method code with the DoubleJump method's code and remove the check for IsGrounded before applying the jump. Otherwise your character has to be on the ground every time. Then remove the DoubleJump method as it is no longer needed. If you're utilizing the DoubleJump as an added skill later in your game then just increase maxJumps as your player earns the skill. Set it to 1 initially so that they have to hit the ground every time.

```
        private void Jump() {
        if (isGrounded) {
            jumpsLeft = maxJumps;
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && jumpsLeft > 0) {
            playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(playerBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
            jumpsLeft--;
        }
    }
```